# How does database load balancing work and how is it kept in sync?

Tags: database, load-balancing

I have been researching about data balancing. It allows the traffic to be distributed among backend servers. But what about the database, since one database server can get overloaded? If we have many database servers then how is it kept synchronized? And shouldn't it happen instantly?

If I create a new account on a website, then the balancer decides on which database server to put my new account information. But if another user loads the page from a different database server, he won't see my new account until the databases are synced? In which case real time collaboration isn't possible.. Or is my understanding here completely wrong?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you talking about?

Comment: I suppose it could apply to any DBMS. How does Google do it for example.

Comment: how do they ensure users get the same data on accessing any datacenter? In the example of chatting or email or user accounts...